# Notify user when destination reached in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, location

My windows phone 8 App requires the end user to get notified or alerted when a destination has reached.
I found some links on how to use service API's, but most of them have only searching the destination. Can we extend the functionality of notifying the user on reaching the destination.
Any suggestive links or API's or code snippets available for the same?.

Thanks In Advance!!..

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the position changed event from the GeoLocator. Once the position you get from this API is within a small distance of the destination, handle accordingly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.positionchanged

Nokia has a nice article about all your options here.
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Get_Phone_Location_with_Windows_Phone_8